# Svelte, on:click event inside each block triggers on page load

Tags: events, onclick, each, svelte, pageload

The problem is that in svelte on:click triggers on page load for some reason. Can anybody explain to me why it's happening and how to prevent it so it only triggers when you actually check the box. This only happens if on:click is inside each block.

```
<script>
    function handleClick(number) {
        alert(number)
    }
    let numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
</script>
{#each numbers as number}
    <input type=checkbox on:click={handleClick(number)}>
{/each}
```

You can look at it [here](https://svelte.dev/repl/19996a3bb68a4f9d845cc183f8f50d94?version=3.23.2)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The value of `on:click` should be a function. You're *invoking* a function — it's no different from doing something like this...

```html
<p>{a} + {b} = {sum(a, b)}</p>
```

...which, as you'd expect, prints *the result of calling* the `sum` function.

Instead, do this:

```html
<input type=checkbox on:click={() => handleClick(number)}>
```

Comment: Ty for the correct reply. Luckily as soon as I wrote the question I understood the problem and solved it in my project.